# Move product data before description in Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

How can I move permanently product data(where is inventory, price etc) before of all tabs in back-end product page in wordpress. Description is not moveable, i tried with drag&drop, but is not working

Comment: Please provide us with an example of what you've already tried: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about the **Metabox** position on the backend, You can simply drag and drop to position them as per your use type.

Comment: Yes, but the long description is not moveable and I cant move the product data before the description